# GridMetrics output does not align with base DTM?

Tags: lidar, grids-graticules, alignment, fusion, grid-metrics

I am trying to derive grid metrics from LiDAR (.las) file using FUSION's `GridMetrics` tool.

My problem is that the output raster from `GridMetrics` does not align with the base DTM used to run the tool.

Command:

```
E:\FUSION\gridmetrics.exe E:\FUSION\testy\N-34-138-B-
b-1-1-4-3.dtm 3 0.5 E:\FUSION\testy\gridmetrics.csv E:\FUSION\testy\*.las
```

Example:

Point is put on the "offset" pixel center.

Raster with "offset" on coordinates:

- Pixel center coordinates are: (628933.5000, 496151.0000)
- Pixel left-upper corner coordinates: (628933.2500, 496151.2500)

[image]

Raster with "proper" coordinates (and my DTM file that goes into `GridMetrics`):

- Pixel center coordinates are: (628933.7500, 496150.7500)
- Pixel left-upper corner coordinates: (628933.5000, 496151.0000)

[image]

How can I turn in `GridMetrics` to output proper pixel coordinates? I also have tried to use switch `/extent`

```
E:\FUSION\gridmetrics.exe /extent:E:\FUSION\testy\N-34-138-B-b-1-1-4-3.dtm E:\FUSION\testy\N-34-138-B-
b-1-1-4-3.dtm 3 0.5 E:\FUSION\testy\gridmetrics.csv E:\FUSION\testy\*.las
```

and `/align`:

```
E:\FUSION\gridmetrics.exe /align:E:\FUSION\testy\N-34-138-B-b-1-1-4-3.dtm E:\FUSION\testy\N-34-138-B-
b-1-1-4-3.dtm 3 0.5 E:\FUSION\testy\gridmetrics.csv E:\FUSION\testy\*.las
```

with my DTM file to no avail.

The raster pixel size is 0.5m. The original DTM was created with LAStools `lasgrid`.

Comment: When I use grid or gridxy with origin of DTM there's no change in pixel corner coordinates.
When i use grid with origin coordinates + 0.25m on both x and y I get desired result.
So, as far as I understand pixel coordinates center (as .0, .0) is hardcoded and requires user to change origin in order to get .0, .0 on pixel corner?

Comment: You are right. +0.25 makes it look all right but in fact, it is moving columns in the wrong way.
-0.25 is making pixel get the right place. Either way, we lose part of information due to moving origin.

Comment: By moving origin we lose part of column where points could lie. I may be mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

**Work around**: use switches `/grid:X,Y,W,H` or `gridxy:X1,Y1,X2,Y2` to manually offset the output grid by inputting its correct extent coordinates.

---

**Misalignment cause** (hypothesis):

Maybe the DTM's header is not being read correctly. It would explain both the misalignment with `GridMetrics` output and also switches `/align` and `/extent` not working, because they are based on the DTM (aka DEM).

Make some tests to corroborate if the DEM's header is related to the root cause.

First, make sure the DEM created from LAStools `lasgrid` is correctly aligned with the point cloud. You can overlay the point cloud over the DEM and visually inspect them, and you can compare the point cloud extents to the DEM's (run `lasinfo` to check point cloud extents).

If everything is OK with DEM (lets call it DEM 1), output it to an [.asc file](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t0000000z000000) (use LAStools `las2las` tool) to check its header info.

If the header has:

- `XLLCENTER` and `YLLCENTER` parameters, change them to `XLLCORNER` and `YLLCORNER` and **minus** offset coordinates with half of the cell size value.
- Otherwise, if it has `XLLCORNER` and `YLLCORNER` parameters, change them to `XLLCENTER` and `YLLCENTER` and **plus** offset coordinates with half of the cell size value.

Convert it back to .dtm (LAStools `las2las`) and this is the DEM 2. Check if DEM 1 and DEM 2 are correctly aligned. Then, run `GridMetrics` again using DEM 2 and verify results.